# Keras can't load model properly when using backend.set_session

Tags: python, keras, backend

The minimum version of my problem is presented as follows

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('model_1.h5')
K.set_session(tf.Session())
state = np.matrix(np.array([1,1,1,1,1]))
model.predict(state)
```

here `model_1.h5` is the saved model constructed by Keras. The code above shows errors

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_2/kernel
```

However, if we `set_session` first as follow

```
K.set_session(tf.Session())
model = load_model('model_1.h5')
state = np.matrix(np.array([1,1,1,1,1]))
model.predict(state)
```

Then everything works fine.

In my real problem, I write a class `deploy` that takes a loaded model as its input. In the initialization of that class, I also use `set_session` to set GPU usage options. Thus, when I initiates `deploy`, `set_session` always run just after the loaded model (similar to the first example given above), which causes the error shown above. Is there any way to fix such problems ?

Comment: Do you customize the created session in your class? What if you first create, customize and set the session and then instantiate your class? Does it work for your scenario?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? I don't understand your opinion exactly.

Comment: I mean do you modify the attributes of your newly created session? Couldn't you create the session first, set it and then load your model and pass it to your class?